# Compute tetrahedral region

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Show that the volume of region $A$ is $1/6$.
Region $A$ is a tetrahedral region in $\mathbb R^3$.
$$A=\{(x,y,z)∈R^3 \mid x\ge 0, y\ge 0, z\ge 0, \text{ and } x+y+z\le 1\}$$

Comment: Use formula $V=\frac{P_ph}{3}$.